# Switch to Jira Simplified Workflow from a second Kanban board within the same project

Tags: kanban, jira

I have created a second Kanban board based on an existing project in Jira.

1. The first board uses the typical Jira workflow and has a column for each issue type.
2. The second board was created with three default columns: Todo, InProgress, Done. All the issue types were automatically mapped in these three columns.

If I press the "Simplify workflow" button from the > Column Management in the second board... Is it going to change anything in the first Kanban board?

Note that I want the original board to stay as is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Workflows are associated with projects and not with boards.

If you have two boards pointing at the same project then any changes you make to the workflow will have an impact on both boards.